# Formatting a method signature loses indentation

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm creating a Code Fix which turns the access modifier of detected methods `public`. The implementation is straightforward: remove all existing access modifiers and add `public` at the front. Afterwards I replace the node and return the solution.

This however results in a modifier list that looks like this: `publicvirtual void Method()`. On top of the modifiers being pasted against eachother, that line of code is wrongly indented. It looks like this:

```
        [TestClass]
        public class MyClass
        {
            [TestMethod]
publicvirtual void Method()
            {

            }
        }
```

So as a solution I format the code instead. Using

```
var formattedMethod = Formatter.Format(newMethod, 
                                       newMethod.Modifiers.Span,
                                       document.Project.Solution.Workspace,
                                       document.Project.Solution.Workspace.Options);
```

I can format the modifiers but they are still wrongly indented:

```
        [TestClass]
        public class MyClass
        {
            [TestMethod]
public virtual void Method()
            {

            }
        }
```

I assume this is because of trivia but prepending the formatted method with the original method's leading trivia does not make a difference. I want to avoid formatting the entire document because, well, this isn't an action to format the entire document.

The entire relevant implementation of this Code Fix:

```
private Task<Solution> MakePublicAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode root, MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
{
    var removableModifiers = new[]
    {
        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.InternalKeyword),
        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ProtectedKeyword),
        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword)
    };

    var modifierList = new SyntaxTokenList()
                            .Add(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                            .AddRange(method.Modifiers.Where(x => !removableModifiers.Select(y => y.RawKind).Contains(x.RawKind)));

    var newMethod = method.WithModifiers(modifierList);
    var formattedMethod = Formatter.Format(newMethod, newMethod.Modifiers.Span, document.Project.Solution.Workspace, document.Project.Solution.Workspace.Options);

    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(method, formattedMethod.WithLeadingTrivia(method.GetLeadingTrivia()));
    var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);

    return Task.FromResult(newDocument.Project.Solution);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `Formatter.Format` manually, just put the `Formatter.Annotation` on your fixed nodes, and the CodeFix engine will call it automatically for you.

The issue is that you need to call `Format` on the root of the tree, but specify the span of the tree you want formatted, otherwise the formatter will run on *just* the tree you pass in, with no context from its parent.

Comment: I was just about to post my solution: if I prepend the trivia to the `SyntaxNode` I receive from `SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)`, all my tests work. Would you say that the formatter annotation solution is preferred to this?

Comment: Yes, generally I would recommend just using the annotation, then it will match the users settings, and get formatted all together with the rest of the changes.

Comment: Where exactly should I apply this annotation? When I do it on method level then the method itself is formatted but the entire method is badly indented. I want to avoid formatting the whole document since that would rather annoying each time you use a code fix.

Comment: You should be able to add it just on the code you add/change.  If this is producing a badly indented method, can you raise an issue on http://roslyn.io with some repro code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my tests indented in the string representation itself, like this:

```
        var original = @"
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class MyClass
        {   
            void Method(Nullable<int> myVar = 5)
            {

            }
        }
    }";
```

As you can see there's still a tab between the left margin and the actual code. Apparently the Roslyn formatter can't handle this scenario (which is, admittedly, not a common situation).

In a situation unlike this though, you're probably interested in the formatter which is why I'll accept Kevin's answer.